# Is there an iPhone video editing app which creates live editable subtitles like the iOS Clips app?

Tags: iphone, ios, video-editing, subtitle

I create short English videos with subtitles for Instagram videos.

My main requirement is that it creates subtitles while I speak that I can then edit.

I’ve been using Clips until now but it is very buggy and has become unusable. I’ve not found any other iOS video editing apps which offer this functionality.

Can you suggest one that does?